# How does this slicing work: `my_string[3:3 + 5]` in Python?

Tags: python, string, slice

I found this in a code handed to me by someone so I want to understand it:

```
my_string = "sulakshana"
truck_id = my_string[3:3 + 5]
```

Output:

```
'aksha'
```

Here, I understand that:
First `3` means start from left and move 3 steps ahead.
`5` means include 5 characters from that direction.

Question : What is that second `3` about? How is it helping  to get this output?

Comment: That's an expression, it means nothing other than addition in this context

Comment: This is just a weird way of writing `aa[3:8]`.

Comment: Why would anyone write it like this?. I just want to understand if there are any benefits.

Comment: @Shravan40 I found this in a code handed to me by someone so I just wanted to understand it.

Comment: I could imagine that they were looking to express "from index 3 to index 5". Otherwise, I see no reason for the addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically when you say `aa[3:3 + 5]` it converts to `aa[3:8]` since 3+5=8. It will start from the 3rd element, and since python indexes from 0, the third element is `a`. The ending index is non-inclusive, so it will go up to 7, which gives you `'aksha'`.

Answer (score 3):

The second 3 is being added together with the 5 to slice the string from the 3rd to 8th indexes (inclusively on the 3rd and exclusively on the 8th). This is equivalent to `aa[3:8]`.

So, I wouldn't say it's exactly "helping" in any way. It all depends on what you wish to accomplish with the slicing.